# Proving that if derivative of f(x) = a with a>0, f(x) must go to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am interested in proving that if derivative of f(x) is a real number c, c>0, as x goes to infinity, f(x) itself must go to infinity.

Seems like a common-sense statement, but don't know how I can approach such proof. Any advice or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Hi: I would integrate the derivative  and then show that it must go to infinity.

Comment: $f'(x) = a \implies f(x) = ax + c$

Comment: @sku I think the OP meant to say that $f'(x)$ is $a$ in the limit as $x\to\infty$, in which case $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=a$ would be the correct interpretation.

Comment: @AllanRosas interpreted the statement as meaning that the derivative goes to a constant at infinity but I thought that it meant that the derivative was a constant everywhere. Re-reading it, I still think my interpretation is correct, but Alann's is also possible. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, for $x_0, x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_0 < x$, there is a $x_0 < y < x$ such that $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(y)(x - x_0)$. Now, taking $x_0$ large enough, we can assume $f'(y) > \frac{c}{2}$ so that $f(x) > f(x_0) + \frac{c}{2}(x - x_0)$. Letting $x \to \infty$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof by contradiction using the definition of the derivative.

Suppose $f(x)$ has a maximum value $M$ and calculate the derivative at the point where it reaches the maximum, $x_M$. By the definition of the derivative, $$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}{f(x+\delta)-f(x)\over \delta}=c,$$ in other words for every positive real number $\epsilon$, no matter how small, there is a $\delta$ such that if $|h|<\delta$ then
$$\left|c-{f(x_M+h)-M\over h}\right|<\epsilon.$$

Now we also have from the supposition that $M$ is maximum that $f(x_M+h)\leq M$, so if $h>0$ then $(f(x_M+h)-M)/h\leq 0$ thus the absolute value of the left hand side is $\geq c$, which contradicts that we can choose $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small as possible.

Comment: I think you should rewrite the definition of the derivative so all the instances of $x$ are replaced with $x_M$'s.

Comment: Possibly, but hopefully people can put things together at this point without too much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=c$ and $c>0$, then $f'(x)>c/2>0$ for all sufficiently large $x$, say for $x\geq a$. This implies that $f$ is increasing on $[a,\infty)$.

We will now argue that $f$ cannot be bounded above. Suppose, for a proof by contradiction, that there is an $M>0$ with $f(x)\leq M$ for every $x$ in $f$'s domain, in particular $[a,\infty)$. Since $f$ is increasing, this implies that $f$ must have a limit at $\infty$, say $L$. Note that then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f'(x)+f(x)\right]=c+L$$

which implies

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\left[f'(x)+f(x)\right]}{e^x}=c+L$$

and consequently

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^xf(x)\right]}{\frac{d}{dx}e^x}=c+L$$

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}$ is the indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$, L'Hopital's rule implies that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=c+L$$

This is impossible because then, from the uniqueness of limits, $c+L=L$ and hence $c=0$, contradicting the assumption that $c>0$. Thus, $f$ cannot have an upper bound, so for any $M>0$, there is an $N\in [a,\infty)$ such that $f(N)>M$. Since $f$ is increasing, we can then assert that $f(x)>M$ for any $x\geq N$, and since $M>0$ was arbitrary, we get $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ by definition.